# Replacement for Index in .NET

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, vb6, indexing

I've been out of doing proper programming for sometime, so as an exercise in trying to get some practice, I'm trying to make a program to solve Sudoku in C# (VS 2010)

My problem occurs when I'm trying to create some form of initial grid for the data out of text boxes. Back when I used to use VB6, I could call all text boxes as a single name and then give them all an index number which would allow me to refer to a specific text box when I was in a loop.

As far as I can see, there's no easily visible equivalent in C# and my searching has been to no avail although I can't imagine it'd be a feature that would be removed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you talk about controls, do you mean on a Windows Forms app, or ASP.NET application, or WPF app?  There are slightly different methods for each

Comment: Hey, I was referring to a Windows Form App =]

Comment: Eric Lippert recently posted some fascinating work on using graphs to eventually produce a sudoku solver. If you're after some background reading, this is a great source! http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/

Comment: Yes, Erics solver comes also at first to my mind. Here is the link to the concrete article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/07/29/graph-colouring-part-five.aspx (This is part 5/5 in a series, maybe you should read the other parts [or the whole blog] too) ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a control array.

http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/674.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go when I get back to my real PC =]

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easier, and look better, if you use a genuine grid control like the [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx).

One bit of bad news. In the days of VB4,5,6 Microsoft used to release a new grid control with every version of Visual Basic, which was annoying (unless you rewrote your code every year). Well, they are [still at it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid.aspx).

Comment: I don't see how that is bad news. The DataGridView has replaced the DataGrid and has been around since .NET 2, and hasn't changed since then. There's no reason to worry about the old DataGrid in VS2010...